# Is it possible to implement the Haversine formula in Objective-C and call it from SQLite?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, haversine, great-circle

As I understand, SQLite doesn't have the math functions to properly implement the [Haversine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula in straight SQL.  I'm thinking this should be possible using an [external function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html), with the implementation being in C.

The goal is to have a SQLite database in an iPhone, and to be able to sort by the distance to the user's current location.  I've searched, but I can't find an example of any examples of this being done.  I think the difficult parts would be getting the function declarations correct.  The end result I'm hoping for, is to be able to execute a SQL statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM LOCATION loc ORDER BY distance(loc.lat, loc.long, ?, ?)
```

I have a C Haversine formula.  The function definition is as follows:

```
float distance( float nLat1, float nLon1, float nLat2, float nLon2 );
```

Does anyone know if this is possible and/or have some example code to start from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had good luck with this post: http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=71

Answer (score 4):

This demonstrates a sqlite function that takes in one string parameter and returns a string result.

In your case you would need a function that reads four floats and returns a float but the principle is the same (you would replace *sqlite3_value_text* with *sqlite3_value_double* and *sqlite3_result_text* with *sqlite3_result_double*):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void haver(sqlite3_context* ctx,int cnt,sqlite3_value** val)
{
    printf("In SQLite haver implementation, called for value: %s\n", sqlite3_value_text(*val));

    char * resultOfCall = "Result of function call"; //this would call the distance function
    sqlite3_result_text(ctx, resultOfCall, strlen(resultOfCall), NULL);
}
int cback (void* udata,int ncol,char** value,char** colname)
{
    int i=0;
    for(;i<ncol;i++)
    printf("Result column: %s value: %s   \n", colname[i], value[i]);
    return 0;
}
int main()
{

    sqlite3 * handle;
    int res = sqlite3_open("./test.sql", &handle);

    res = sqlite3_create_function(handle, "haver", 1, SQLITE_UTF8, NULL, &haver, NULL, NULL);

    char * errmsg = NULL;   
    res = sqlite3_exec(handle, "select haver(w) from t", &cback, NULL, &errmsg);
    printf("sqlite3_exec result: %d %s\n", res, errmsg != NULL ? errmsg : "No error");

    sqlite3_close(handle);
}
```